# Django : accessing uploaded picture from ImageField

Tags: django, imagefield

Hi I'm having a problem about referring to uploaded images in HTML.

I'm using ImageField to save profile pictures :

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='stories/static/stories/profile_images/', blank=True)
```

As you can see, It'll upload to `<App folder>/static/stories/profile_images/`

Then I refer it in HTML like this :

```
<div class="profilepic" style="background-image: url('/{{ x.writer.picture }}');"></div>
```

Which directs to

> ROOT/stories/static/stories/profile_images/.jpg

Instead of

> ROOT/static/stories/profile_images/.jpg

Any ideas?

(I'm trying to reverse-truncate the first 8 character, but there is not built-in template filter available)

Answer (score 1):

since your `upload_to` is `stories/static/stories/profile_images/`, it IS showing right path:

```
ROOT/stories/static/stories/profile_images/.jpg
```

and one more thing, you need `.url` to get the picture with its path

```
{{ x.writer.picture.url }}
```

Comment: but the picture has to be referred as
**DOMAIN/static/stories/profile_images/.jpg**
so 
**DOMAIN/stories/static/stories/profile_images/.jpg**
doesn't work :(

Comment: @Lumsum "DOMAIN/static/stories/profile_images/.jpg" is not the expected one which is wrong. so you want the "wrong one" ?

Comment: Yes, because the picture exists in the "wrong" path (I test with <img>). I think it's because of the URLConf, so I need the wrong path.

Comment: @Lumsum then just change your ``MEDIA_URL`` and ``MEDIA_ROOT`` to wrong one, then you will get it.

Comment: The picture file exist in ROOT/stories/static/...
but to access it in a browser I need to refer to 
DOMAIN/static... but from {{ x.writer.picture.url }} I got 
DOMAIN/stories/static/.. so is there any way to truncate the first 8 characters from the url?

Comment: It's OK now. I created a custom filter. Thank you very much.